# Eloquent Querying pivot table for all users - and also include records where there is no users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm querying a table, which finds all tasks assigned to a given user (the one signed in).

I have a pivot table for the tasks/users relation, as more than one user can be assigned to a task. The function below successfully grabs all the tasks the user is assigned too. No issue there.

***However***, I also want to include tasks that NO users have been assigned to in the function below (in my platform, no users assigned to a task means it's for "everyone").

```
$user_tasks = Team::currentTeam()->tasks()->with('user', 'comments')->whereHas('user', function($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this should work:

```
$user_tasks = Team::currentTeam()->tasks()->with('user', 'comments')->whereHas('user', function($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})->doesntHave('user','or')->get();
```

because there is no function orDoesntHave. There's only:

```
public function doesntHave($relation, $boolean = 'and', Closure $callback = null)
{
    return $this->has($relation, '<', 1, $boolean, $callback);
}
```

defined, so you need to use `doesntHave` and specify operator as 2nd argument.

Comment: Thanks. What's the 'or' and default 'and' $boolean?

Comment: @MikeBarwick This is operator that will be used when generating query - you might have either `A and B` in SQL query or `A or B`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unassigned tasks separately:

```
$unassigned_tasks = Task::unassigned()->get(); // Uses a scope that says where user_id is null
```

And then something like:

```
$user_tasks->tasks->push($unassigned_tasks);
```